# Unity PropertyDrawer PropertyField Slider value cannot be typed in manually

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm currently writing a small PropertyDrawer for a specific class I want to display in a List. This class only has 2 variables, here is the Code:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Spawnable
{
    public GameObject spawnablePrefab = null;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int spawnChance = 50;
}
```

What I want to achieve is, that both these will be displayed next to each other instead of below each other to save space in a list view. I managed to do that, by creating a PropertyDrawer for this class:

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(RandomSpawner.Spawnable))]
public class SpawnablePropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
   public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
   {
       EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

       position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

       Rect objectRect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width / 2 - 2, position.height);
       Rect chanceRect = new Rect(position.x + position.width / 2 + 2, position.y, position.width / 2 - 2, position.height);

       EditorGUI.PropertyField(objectRect, property.FindPropertyRelative("spawnablePrefab"), GUIContent.none);
       EditorGUI.PropertyField(chanceRect, property.FindPropertyRelative("spawnChance"), GUIContent.none);

       EditorGUI.EndProperty();
   }
}
```

The problem I ran into now is, that because the int value has the [Range]-Attribute, it is displayed as a slider with a value field next to it (and I do want this) but I cannot click the value field to type in a value manually. I also can't just display it as a slider directly in that PropertyDrawer, because I can't access the [Range]-Attribute.

Sadly my stackoverflow-Account doesn't have enough reputation to post images yet, so here is  a link to a gif I made that shows the Problem:

[image: enter link description here]

Does anybody know how to change this behaviour so I can click the value-Field to type in some value directly?

Comment: Have you tried removing other draw calls? I suppose one of them may be overlapping the textfield, PrefixLabel looks suspicios since it covers all the property drawer position.

Comment: @PawełŁęgowski where would I find other draw calls for this? I only have this Property Drawer. There is a Custom Inspector for the component, but it only draws the default inspector and adds some buttons at the end

Comment: `position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);`
       
       `EditorGUI.PropertyField(objectRect, property.FindPropertyRelative("spawnablePrefab"), GUIContent.none);` remove these and check if it still behaves like that

Comment: @PawełŁęgowski okay, that did the trick. I tried it without these two and the slider worked as expected. After that I added the first PropertyField again and it still worked. So in my List, I don't have the Element-Number-Label anymore, but to be honest I never really needed that in the first place so thank you very much :) The Problem has to do with the way I get the position. Don't know why that is problematic but I take the workaround

Comment: I suppose if you change rect in        `position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);` you can still have that label, just make sure they do not overlap because it may cause problems